# How to configure Spring boot 2.4 server threads in undertow?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, undertow

How to configure spring boot server threads (for both IO and Worker) for undertow embedded server?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As per the [documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.4.0/reference/htmlsingle/#server.undertow.threads.io):

```
server.undertow.threads.io //Number of I/O threads to create for the worker. The default is derived from the number of available processors.
server.undertow.threads.worker //Number of worker threads. The default is 8 times the number of I/O threads.
```